# Qt ComboBox->addItem() Integer to Qstring conversion error?

Tags: qt, combobox, qcombobox

I am really new to Qt and I have a little question for you. I am trying to work on ComboBox and when I add items to a combobox an integer like;

```
 combobox->addItem(class.value); // class.value is an integer
```

It just adds a symbol to the combobox (*, / or ? ) 
How can I solve this little problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `combobox->addItem(QString::number(class.value));`

Answer (score 1):

Use [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) . Advantage of using QVariant over QString::number() is you can convert data of any type to any other type.

**int to string**

```
 QVariant(32).toString(); //assuming calss.value to be int
```

in your case it will be

```
combobox->addItem(QVariant(class.value).toString());
```

**float to a string**

```
QVariant(3.2).toString();
```

**string to a float:**

```
 QVariant("5.2").toFloat();
```

it is that easy.